# Load page in Iframe based on url string

Tags: php, redirect, iframe

I want make a iframe that load different page based on url strings.

Iframe is a small box on my page.

If url www.example.com/loo
Then iframe show loo.php

IF www.example.com/boo
Then iframe show boo.php

So if the user click a link on my main page like 
example.com/loobar.html
example.com/loodart.html

The iframe should show loo.php because the url contain the word "loo"

Is this possible to do?
I created a  .htaccess file in the iframe folder there all pages are for iframe box.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} loo
RewriteRule .* https://example.com/iframe/loo.php
```

That does not work, think the iframe htaccess not reading the main website url??

Hope you guys understand.